# Error! Invalid constructor arguments provided. Please verify that they are in ABI-encoded format, I tried (https://abi.hashex.org/) but still no luck

Tags: solidity, ropsten, constructor

Good afternoon!
I want to create a NFT and my code is working fine in remix.
An error occurred while adding source code to ropsten: Error! Invalid constructor arguments provided. Please verify that they are in ABI-encoded format

I even tried ABI encoding with https://abi.hashex.org/ it did not work either.

My constructor is not having any arguments as well
Ropsten contract address is 0x4Fa54f83D7951733CCb46e1F66b267Bee28Ccbb3

Comment: Hi, first using remix is not very good for developing :) u need to use truffle or hardhat. And those frameworks has tools and library to verify code https://hardhat.org/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-etherscan.html

Comment: What's the source code? What's the solidity version? What were the compilation parameters? What's the license? If the constructor doesn't have parameters you shouldn't provide any.